# Understand the behaviour of a widget value in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using a simple Shiny app as an example :
I would like to make sure that the widget "myselection" is informed before continuing my treatments in my application.
That's why I use `print(myselection)` to check the value and `req(myselection)`.
But it doesn't render any text this way.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Example"),
  mainPanel(
    actionButton("validate_see", "Validate to see inputs"),
    uiOutput("myselection_ui"),
    textOutput("mysentence_ui")
  )
)


server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$validate_see, {
    
    output$myselection_ui <- renderUI({
      selectInput("myselection", label = h3("Select box"), 
                  choices = list("","tx_marge","tx_VA"), 
                  selected = "")
    })
    
    print(input$myselection)
    req(input$myselection)
    
    output$mysentence_ui <- renderText({
      paste0("Your choice is : ",input$myselection)
    })
  })
 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And if I comment the line with `req(input$myselection)` it works
`print(myselection)` is printed as NULL.
I would like to understand why ??
Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `input$myselection` anywhere in the `server` code. The `req` and `print` value should be inside `renderText` -

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Example"),
  mainPanel(
    actionButton("validate_see", "Validate to see inputs"),
    uiOutput("myselection_ui"),
    textOutput("mysentence_ui")
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$validate_see, {
    
    output$myselection_ui <- renderUI({
      selectInput("myselection", label = h3("Select box"), 
                  choices = list("","tx_marge","tx_VA"), 
                  selected = "")
    })
    
    output$mysentence_ui <- renderText({
      req(input$myselection)
      print(input$myselection)
      paste0("Your choice is : ",input$myselection)
    })
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```